# Soft shadow for Unity UI Image

Tags: unity-game-engine

What is the best approach to implement a soft shadow around the outline of a Unity UI Image? I want to achieve the effect below:

[image: desired-soft-shadow]

(Image Source: [YouTube video: Soft Shadow UI || Unity 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKW-ksPbgW4))

My current approach is to manually add a shadow Image behind the main Image. For example, see below screenshots:

[image: button-with-soft-shadow]

[image: scene-heirarchy]

[image: shadow-inspector]

However, I find this approach tedious and messy from a workflow perspective, because I have to manually add this shadow GameObject to my GameObject hierarchy every time I want to add a soft shadow to a UI Image.

While I think it's possible to improve on this current workflow slightly, is there a better approach?

---

Note that I also tried Unity's [built-in Shadow effect component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Shadow.html):

[image: built-in-drop-shadow]

This is a drop shadow and not a soft shadow effect I am looking for.

But I think this approach shows an ideal workflow, where it's as simple as adding a shadow component to a GameObject with an Image.

Comment: this is not the correct place to ask this question, this has nothing to do with programming or the code you have tried, but isnt working. It is better to ask this question at the Gamedev stackexchange: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hm unfortunately I think there is currently only that hard shadow component ... However the source code for that is actually online: [Shadow.cs](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0bd08e22bc17bdf80bf7b997a4b43877ae4ee9ac/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/VertexModifiers/Shadow.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [Outline.cs](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0bd08e22bc17bdf80bf7b997a4b43877ae4ee9ac/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/VertexModifiers/Outline.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default) ... so someone could try and make a custom version of it supporting soft shadows ^^

Comment: I actually tried and looked at the source code ... unfortunately it won't be that easy to change it to soft shadows ... It is kind of copying the 6 vertices of the Uzi and making a colored overlay out of that ... For softshadows it would be necessary to somehow splitting those original 2 triangles into multiple and change the alpha accordingly .. but in general it should be possible ... Anyway in your place for now I would stick to the "image" way you are using already

Comment: But maybe with the Outline it is easier to control and one could try to manipulate the outline to kind of "fake" a softshadow as the image approach does

Comment: @derHugo thanks for your comments. I was thinking about looking at your approach too, I’ll let you know if I work on it and manage to figure something out

Comment: Any luck with your research @sonny?

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΜπίλης not yet, I haven’t looked into it much yet because I’m working on other things, but I will post an update if I find anything else in the future. The only things I can think of right now is what derHugo suggested, and maybe an approach related to materials & shaders.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΜπίλης just FYI I posted a new answer

Comment: @Jan just FYI I posted a new answer

Comment: @derHugo just FYI I posted a new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Procedural UI Image](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/procedural-ui-image-52200) by Josh H on the Unity Asset Store looks promising.

> Create an infinite number of basic shapes without a ton of image
> resources. Control and animate border-width and border-radius. It is
> perfect for creating flat styled UI. Easy to understand and
> well-commented code along with a PDF documentation will keep this
> package extendable.
>
> Main features:
>
> [...]
>
> ➤ Fall-off: can be used for soft shadow effect or glow

[image: fall-off-distance-param]

---

Other "procedural UI" packages may also support soft shadows.

There are some new UI assets on the Asset Store that have been released since this question was asked, e.g. [True Shadow - UI Soft Shadow and Glow (beta)](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/true-shadow-ui-soft-shadow-and-glow-beta-176322) by Tai's Assets.

Answer (score 2):

I would split the current shadow you have into 3 images: corner, edge, background.

Then, I'd make a script that instanciate those images onto all corners, edges, and below the element you're shadowing (for the backgound) with the correct size & orientation.

The script would also handle those parameters:

- *float* Intensity (actually changes alpha tranparency)
- *float* Spread (streches the images out)
- *Vector3* Position (simple translation in case you want your shadow to be shifted from the image you're shadowing)

You would then be able to use it for any element.